# Git retrieving lost branches

Tags: git, version-control, branch

So I decided I wanted to change a branch name,
and instead of creating a new branch I thought I will use this method, to rewrite the whole branch, but what it actually did was delete all my remote branches.

Any idea how I might get them back.
(Please note that I had more branches, but hopefully this will do)

> → git push -f --mirror
>   Counting objects: 3, done.
>   Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
>   Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
>   Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 323 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
>   Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
>   remote: This repository moved. Please use the new location:
>   remote:   ----
>   To ----
>    - [deleted]         some_branch
>    - [deleted]         another_branch
>    * [new branch]      support_page_changes -> support_page_changes
>    * [new branch]      origin/master -> origin/master
>    * [new branch]      origin/another_branch -> origin/another_branch
>    * [new branch]      origin/some_branch -> origin/some_branch

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git reflog` to get the SHA1 of the last commits you used. Once you find the right commit, just check it out, and create a branch there. For instance, if you find that your branch was previously on commit with SHA-1 xyz, then you just need to do

```
git checkout xyz
git branch my_brach
```

If you can't find the SHA-1 with `git reflog`, you may try to list all the commit not accessible by references:

```
git fsck --full --no-reflogs # don't worry if it takes time to run

#Now, let's see what are the commits show by the previous command
git show abc
git show def
...
```